# Using Promise.reject() in async/await catch handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I just wanted to know if it's a good practice to use the following code:

```
   const myFun = async () => {
     try {
         const response = await api();
         if(response.status === 200) {
            return response.data;
         }
      } catch(err) {
         return Promise.reject(err);
      }
   }
```

Here `myFun` will return a resolved/reject Promise that will be caught by another function. I just wanted to know if this is right way or are there any alternatives?

Comment: For a function marked as async the correct way is to `throw`

Comment: What do you want to happen when the promise resolves, but status code is not 200?  You are resolving with `undefined` when that happens now which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are achieving nothing by trying to re-throw the error from `api()`.

Using `async` function will cause `Promise.reject(error)` to be called implicitly when an error is thrown anyway.

Just write your function like this:

```
const myFun = async () => {
     const response = await api();
     if (response.status === 200) {
          return response.data;
     }
     // You might want to return something else here
}
```

Then the calling function will still receive the error:

```
try {
    await myFun();
} catch (error) {
    // error still received
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is mixing async/await and Promises. You can just `throw` the `err` from inside the catch block.

```
const myFun = async () => {
     try {
         const response = await api();
         if(response.status === 200) {
            return response.data;
         }
      } catch(err) {
         throw err;
      }
   }
```

After this you can catch the error wherever you call `myFun`.

The end result in both cases would be the same. The only difference is that `throw` can be used anywhere in JS code but `Promise.reject` can only be called from within an asynchronous code block only

Comment: Ah I see. Can I know the difference between doing `throw err` and `throw new Error(err)` ?

Comment: They aren't mixing `async/await` and promises.  `Async/await` are entirely based on promises so that portion of your answer is  just the wrong way to say it.  In addition, they don't even need the try catch.  If all they want to do is to return a rejected promise when the `await` rejects, then you can just remove the entire `try/catch` as `async/await` will automatically return reject the promise that the `async` function returns if the `await` rejects.  So, skip the `try/catch` entirely.

Comment: Your `throw err` is no better than `return Promise.reject(err)`.  They accomplish the exact same thing.  Also, the OP returns NOTHING when `response.status` is not `200` which is another problem.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 I get now. What do you suggest doing when statuscode is not 200? I'm relatively new to async stuff

Comment: I don't know what the OP wants when it's not 200.  I posted a comment to their question to ask them.  Probably if it's not 4xx or 5xx they want to reject, but if its 2xx or 3xx they might want to do something specific to the status code.

Comment: The try..catch here serves no purpose, as it throws the exact same error.

Comment: @jfriend00 i understand what you're saying but the OP asked for alternatives and i suggested that only. And in regards to the mixing I meant something more on the lines of the syntax they are using. I agree with Johnathan too that the throwing it again serves no purpose. But that was not what OP asked for.

Comment: The best answers here don't recommend poor or useless code which is what the `catch` and `throw err` is here, regardless of what the OP asked for.  That was the point of my comment.  I didn't downvote you.  I pointed out a way your answer could be improved and wanted others who read this answer and wanted the OP to know that the catch here is superfluous.  You could improve your answer further.